# Voice Over for iOS is not reading the self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, voiceover

Unfortunately I cannot post code for security reasons. I will do my best to describe.

In the navigation bar, the navigationItem.titleView is being read. However when I swipe right for voice over, it does not read the navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. The element is accessible as when I press the button itself, it is being read.

I have tried grouping the elements. Doing something like

```
[self.navigationItem.accessibilityElements = @[self.navigationItem.titleView,self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem]];
```

Has also not worked. Basically the main issue is the navigation.

Comment: Is `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` accessible?